# How can I use the explode function on an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the following array stored in the variable $players :

```
$players = array('Brian,9,9,6,7','Stan,8,8,8,9','Alice,8,6,8,8',
                'Bella,8,7,9,9','Sam,9,9,9,7','Bill,8,8,8,9',
                'John,8,8,8,8','Amanda,6,7,7,9','Walton,9,4,7,6',
                'Marcus,10,10,8,9','Eddie,8,6,8,8','Angela,8,7,9,9',
                'Joseph,5,9,6,7','Ezra,6,6,7,9','Dallas,7,7,7,6',
                'Forrest,6,7,8,9','Rhett,8,8,9,9','Wayne,10,10,4,7',
                'Jason,8,8,8,8');
```

I need to explode the values in the array between each comma. So the output will look something like this:

```
Brian 9 9 6 7 
Stan 8 8 8 9 etc.
```

How would I achieve this ? I have tried using implode to convert the array into a string and then using explode but that is not working. I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you mean a single array of all values? `explode(',', implode(',' $players))` would do that.

Comment: Clarify your desired output.

Comment: Yes, a single array of all values. I want the output to be formatted as shown below:  Brian 9 9 6 7 
Stan 8 8 8 9 8
Alice 8 6 8 8 
Bella 8 7 9 9 
Sam 9 9 9 7 
Bill 8 8 8 9 
John 8 8 8 8 
Amanda 6 7 7 9 
Walton 9 4 7 6
Marcus 10 10 8 9 
Eddie 8 6 8 8 
Angela 8 7 9 9 
Joseph 5 9 6 7 
Ezra 6 6 7 9 
Dallas 7 7 7 6 
Forrest 6 7 8 9 
Rhett 8 8 9 9 
Wayne 10 10 4 7 
Jason 8 8 8 8

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
   $array[$key] = str_replace(',', ' ', $val);
}
```

Output:

```
array(
   'Brian 9 9 6 7',
   'Stan 8 8 8 9',
   ...
)
```